# Does the synthesis flow always require writing a wrapper? If so, where do the signals that we use as inputs come from?

Tags: synthesis, register-transfer-level, synopsys-vcs

I understand what it means when we say we write a wrapper of an RTL code block, that is to create an interface of it with the rest. My question is, when I do synthesis, I also need to write a wrapper of my top level module? If so, as this is my top level already, how should I write a wrapper such that my synthesis tool would understand?

I tried to synthesize with my top level which did not work, as it seems I am encountering some errors with hierarchical names.